# Generating integers of form 2^n - 1 with for loop

Tags: java, loops, sequences

I have an assignment that asks me to write a for loop inside a method that will output this sequence:

> 1 3 7 15 31 ... 255

I know that the pattern is to multiply the number by two then add one (or just to add the exponents of 2 to each number so 1 + 2 = 3 + 4 = 7 + 8 = 15 etc.) but I don't know how exactly to make a loop that'll output that sequence all the way up to 255.

I would just like an example or explanation to guide me a little bit, I don't want anyone to actually give me the exact code I need. Here's what I've done so far:

```
public static void methodOne() {
    for (int j = 1; j <= 255; j *= 2) {

    }
}
```

I tried to use another for loop within the for loop above but it didn't work well, and I'm not sure if that's the right thing to do. I basically want to take `j` and have it multiplied by two and then add 1 to get the next number in the sequence.

Comment: Why not `j = j*2 + 1` instead of `j *= 2`?

Comment: For fun, you can use `j *= 1/j + 2` ;) caution with the float type

Answer (score 4):

As you noted, the sequence is to double the previous number and add one. Just have your `for` loop progress like that, and print the number in each iteration:

```
for (int j = 1; j <= 255; j = (j * 2) + 1) {
    System.out.println(j);
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much, I actually didn't think of that. I did something like that where I did j*=2+1 but instead it just ended up being j * 3 (which makes sense, I didn't separate the 2 and 1 and what not).

I appreciate it, sorry for homework question that's pretty easy to do, I'm new to Java and I thought it was harder than it had to be.

Answer (score 1):

As is howework, will leave you something to think:

```
for x in 2:8 range
result = 2^x -1
```

Answer (score 0):

this is the most succinct form I could think of that uses only **additions ( + )** over 1 single tracking variable:

```
 jot 100 |
```

> ```
> mawk '$++NF = _+=_++' CONVFMT='%.f' # mawk-1
> gawk '$++NF = _+=_++'               # gawk, mawk-2, nawk, etc
> ```

```
1 1
2 3
3 7
4 15
5 31
6 63
7 127
8 255
9 511
10 1023
11 2047
12 4095
13 8191
14 16383
15 32767
16 65535
17 131071
18 262143
. . .
30 1073741823
31 2147483647
32 4294967295
33 8589934591
34 17179869183
35 34359738367
36 68719476735
```

if you wanna go all the way to `2^1023 - 1` without using a big-int library (tested and confirmed working for `mawk-1`, `mawk-2`, `gawk 5.2.0`, and `nawk`):

```
 jot 1023 |
```

> ```
> mawk '$++NF = (((___+=___++)%((_+=_^=_<_)+_*_*_)^_^_)%_ ||
>               index(___,"e") < (length(___) < _^_^_--))  \
>               ? ___ : sprintf("%.*s%d", -_+(__ = length(_=\
>                       sprintf("%.f",___))),_,substr(_,__)-!!__)' \
>                                                     CONVFMT='%.16g'
> ```

```
  31 2147483647

 279 9713344461128645354597309534117594533212034195260697606259062048
     69452142602604249087

 527 4393470502483590217588416511412091659052438592091715462012456613
     8787476373744998733584381700233309151854696392905477491437580723
     1981865204004737810631363657727

 775 1987223158144907436990693745232003270728814101909371662257986608
     6733452194385624145035243633006674917766242952923277737038996224
     5646696242104868771205271185818170236930668787910433956560844600
     937633663896795708000114284397288455405567

1023 8988465674311579538646525953945123668089884894711532863671504057
     8866337902750481566354238661203768010560056939935696678829394884
     4072083112464237153197370621888839467124327426381511098006230470
     5972654147604250288441907534117123144073695655527041361858167525
     5342293149119973622969239858152417678164812112068607
```